# JSON object from ArrayList<CustomClass> always overwriting previous one. how to solve?

Tags: java, android, json, list, arraylist

I am trying to create JSon from ArrayList.
Assuming list size is dynamic, here is what i am trying to do ...

```
JSONArray arry = new JSONArray();
for (GroupItem gi : list) {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("fieldName", gi.fieldName);
  obj.put("fieldName2", gi.fieldName2);
  arry.put(obj);
}
```

but it holds only last value!!!

I want to add all values available in list.
Array is retaining last obj data ...

How to solve this?

Comment: You need to put new json object in the array everytime.

Comment: and how can i do that in simple way? @Harry

Comment: I think your code will work, How you printed your array? System.err.println(arry.toString());

Comment: I think you should add the jsonObject not put it. How about "arry.add(obj);"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
JSONArray arry = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj;

for (GroupItem gi : list)
{
   obj = new JSONObject();
   obj.put("fieldName", gi.fieldName);
   obj.put("fieldName2", gi.fieldName2);
   arry.put(obj);
}
```

Comment: ohk let me try @Davidhons